# How to uninstall completely from centos?

Tags: linux, centos6, redis

I have installed redis by following instructions.

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ cd redis-5.0.5
$ make
```

but I don't know how to uninstall now. Please let us share how to completely uninstall redis 5.0.5 from centos 6.10

Comment: There may be a `make uninstall` option.  If not, you'll need to examine the makefile to see where `make install` copies files/directories to and manually remove them.

Comment: but redis created Database files while installing?

Comment: Then you'd need to `drop` those tables, etc. as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you didn't run `make install` there is nothing installed yet.
Just remove the directory

```
rm -rf redis-5.0.5
```

Comment: i have already installed. then what should i do?

Comment: Then post your complete steps, not only part of it.

Comment: already posted steps in 1st post. i just installed.

Comment: What you posted is not an installation. It's just the compilation of source code. It's not installed until you run `make install` (which you did NOT post).

Comment: https://redis.io/download you can see here the installation guideline.

Comment: That guide confirms what I wrote.

Comment: root@server.domain.com [~]# rm -rf redis-5.0.5
root@server.domain.com[~]#

Its just return blank.

Comment: Good. It's gone.

Comment: so, do you mean Redis is not installed yet, if wanna install, then it should be make install ?

Comment: Why i am seeing if removed? root@server.domain.com [~]# redis-server --version Redis server v=5.0.5 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=dd9490a63278a7ca root@server.domain.com [~]#

Comment: @noglobalads Nothing in your question shows that you have installed anything at all. Please edit your question to show what you have actually done.